# Python (requests library) ETL: Spotify API "Authorization Code Flow" - Request Access Token Problem

Tags: python, python-requests, etl, spotify

**Context:**

> I'm working on a side project to pull data from the Spotify API into a
> Microsoft SQL Server database as part of a refreshing ETL job. I need
> to use the "Authorization Code Flow" so I can authorize/authenticate
> programmatically, so my table will populate each day.
>
> I'm using the Python requests library for this, and I don't want to
> make an Object Oriented Solution for this if possible (not my
> preference).

**Problem:**

> I'm having trouble getting the Access Token after authenticating.
> Looking at similar issues, it's very similar to this one:
> [Spotify API Authorization Code Flow with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435932/spotify-api-authorization-code-flow-with-python)
> .
>
> I'm not sure why I'm getting a Response 400 (Bad Request) from this.
> Can someone please advise here?

**Code:**

```
# used to to encode byte string from CLIENT_ID : CLIENT_SECRET, then decode for Authentication Header
import base64

# used to make HTTP requests from Spotify API
import requests

# used to access the environment variables
import os

def request_user_authorization():
    '''
        HTTP GET request to gain access to data (Authorization Code Flow)
        HTTP POST request to send the code and receive an Authorization Token (current issue)

        https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/
    '''
    # URLs
    AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
    TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
    BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1'

    SPOTIFY_URI = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played'

    # sensitive items
    CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID_ENV')
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET_ENV')

    # make a request to the /authorize endpoint to get an authorization code
    user_authorization_code = requests.get(
        AUTH_URL, {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'response_type': 'code',
            'redirect_uri': SPOTIFY_URI,
            'scope':  'user-read-recently-played',
        }
    )

    # Code 200 = "OK"
    print(user_authorization_code)

    #----------------------------------------------------------#
    api_header_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode((CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET).encode('ascii'))

    api_headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % api_header_string.decode('ascii')
    }

    api_payload = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': user_authorization_code,
        'redirect_uri': SPOTIFY_URI,
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET
    }

  #issue here: 

    # Make a request to the /token endpoint to get an access token
    access_token_request = requests.post(url=TOKEN_URL, data=api_payload, headers=api_headers)
    
    # returns <Response [400]>

    # https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics/
        # 15.5.1.  400 Bad Request

        #    The _400 (Bad Request)_ status code indicates that the server cannot
        #    or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to
        #    be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
        #    message framing, or deceptive request routing).

#     print(access_token_request)
    #----------------------------------------------------------#


request_user_authorization()
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood how the Authorizatuon Code Flow works.

The `redirect_uri` in this kind of flow is used by the provider api (here spotify) as a callback to give you the authorization code.

The spotify API will call this url with a `code` parameter that you can use to ask for a token.

Meaning that for this flow to work you need a web server ready to receive requests on the uri that you have given in your code request (and specified when creating your app on the spotify developer portal). You **might** be better off using the Client Credentials Flow for your use case.

Also you should always use the name of the keywords arguments when using `requests.get`,  `requests.post` ... It makes the code clearer and the order of the arguments differ for each method so it can get confusing if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

@Speedlulu you're correct, that was the problem.

For anyone in the future reading this question: this is what I learned since posting the question:

What I misunderstood was the flow of data, and that Client Credentials Flow (Application to Spotify only) was the better choice because I don't need to have a "User" portion to this program.

Spotify's Client Credentials Flow Documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/

```
# used to access environment variables securely (sensitive data)
import os

# used to encode strings into bytes and back
import base64

# used to convert JSON data into strings
import json

# endpoint that I'm connecting to on Spotify's servers
token_request_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID_ENV')
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET_ENV')

# encode credentials into bytes, then decode into a string for the HTTP POST request to Spotify to authenticate
BASE64_ENCODED_HEADER_STRING = base64.b64encode(bytes(f"{CLIENT_ID}:{CLIENT_SECRET}", "ISO-8859-1")).decode("ascii")

#initializing dictionaries for HTTP POST request
headers = {}
data = {}

headers['Authorization'] = f"Basic {BASE64_ENCODED_HEADER_STRING}"

data['grant_type'] = "client_credentials"
data['json'] = True
data['scope'] = 'user-read-recently-played'

r = requests.post(url=token_request_url, headers=headers, data=data)

# prints the response from the server regarding the access token data (formatted to be easier to read)
print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))    
  
# store the token value in a variable for HTTP GET request  
token = r.json()['access_token']
```

What was unclear is that I first need to POST my request with the credentials to get the token (using the specific URL to do), store the r.json()['access_token'] value in a variable, then use that as part of the following GET request to access my specific data.