# Spotify web API call gives wrong code (Python)

Tags: python, spotify

To get an authorization code from the Spotify web API I use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435932/spotify-api-authorization-code-flow-with-python):

```
AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'

CLIENT_ID = '******'
CLIENT_SECRET = '*****'

auth_code = requests.get(AUTH_URL, {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'response_type': 'code',
    'redirect_uri': 'uri',
    'scope': 'playlist-modify-private',
})

auth_header = base64.urlsafe_b64encode((CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET).encode())
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % auth_header.decode('ascii')
}

payload = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': auth_code,
    'redirect_uri': 'uri',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
}
access_token_request = requests.post(url=TOKEN_URL, data=payload, headers=headers)
access_token_response_data = access_token_request.json()
access_token = access_token_response_data['access_token']
```

Only the `auth_code` for getting the code from Spotify gives <Response 200> instead the code. What could be wrong?

I tried to print the auto code but it gives <Response 200> back. This is ultimately used in the call to Spotify for the token.

Comment: Why not using [spotipy](https://pypi.org/project/spotipy/) ?

Answer (score 1):

`Authorization Code Flow` in spotify needs a server feature at application side.

It can get `code` value from spotify server, then request token with `code`.

In code flow diagram, explain detail [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/)

[image]

I will demo with [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/)

File save as `spotify-client.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
REDIRECT_URI = '<your callback URI>' # my case is 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
CLIENT_ID = "<your client id>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>"
SCOPE = [
    "user-read-email",
    "playlist-read-collaborative"
]

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    spotify = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, scope=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    authorization_url, state = spotify.authorization_url(AUTH_URL)
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route("/callback", methods=['GET'])
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    res = requests.post(TOKEN_URL,
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
        data={
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI
        })
    return json.dumps(res.json())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000,debug=True)
```

#### Steps

#1 Run Application

```
python spotify-client.py
```

#2 Open Browser and access this URL

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

#3 Login with your Spotify credential
This login screen automatically shows to you.

[image]

#4  The `access-token` will shows on your browser if success login.

[image]