# Spotify API python {'status': 404, 'message': 'Invalid username'}}

Tags: python, spotify

```
import refresh_token
import requests
import os
import base64
import json
from requests import post

def get_token():
    desired_scope = 'ugc-image-upload playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user- 
    read-currently-playing'
    id = os.environ.get('client_id')
    secret = os.environ.get('client_secret')
    url = "http://localhost:8000/callback/"


    auth_string = f'{os.environ.get("client_id")}:{os.environ.get("client_secret")}'
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,"Content-Type": "application/x-www- 
    form-urlencoded"}
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers,data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    print(token)
    return token


def get_currently_playing(token):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,}
    url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())

    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_json = response.json()
        if response_json['is_playing']:
            track_name = response_json['item']['name']
            artist_name = response_json['item']['artists'][0]['name']
            album_name = response_json['item']['album']['name']
            return f'You are currently listening to {track_name} by {artist_name} from the album {album_name}.'
        else:
            return 'You are not currently listening to any music.'
    else:
        return 'Unable to get currently playing track.'


access_token = get_token()
song = get_currently_playing(access_token)
print(song)
```

This code will produce the error
{'error': {'status': 404, 'message': 'Invalid username'}}
and print Unable to get currently playing track.

When I run the code I get this 404 error which says I have an invalid username. I don't understand, are you suppost to add your username somewhere? I've tried adding username to headers but nothing seems to work

Comment: You are trying to use [Client credentials](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow#:~:text=Since%20this%20flow%20does%20not%20include%20authorization%2C%20only%20endpoints%20that%20do%20not%20access%20user%20information%20can%20be%20accessed.) with **Authorization** scopes. [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292843/7111585) on how to implement the Authorization code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using client credentials. To use player API you need to use server sided authorization (OAuth), take a look at this [Spotify guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization).