# Spotify API - Cannot get recently played songs

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

> I want to get my recently played songs using Python.

I created an APP on the Spotify Developers website. I have the Client ID and the Client Secret. I managed to use these to use the `search` function to find the `artist_id` of an artist, and grab their top tracks. Hence, my credentials work.

I now want to grab my recently played tracks, but I keep getting errors. Initially, I got an `insufficient client scope error`, but now I get a `Server Error` (Response 500). Unclear why.

## Code

```
import os
import json
import base64
from requests import post, get
from datetime import datetime


client_id = "CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET"


def get_token():
    """Grabs Access Token"""
    # Generate Authorization string in Base64
    auth_string = client_id + ":" + client_secret
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    # Generate URL, Headers, and Data for Post request
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scope": "user-read-recently-played"
    }

    # Post request
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    # Transform to dictionary
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token


def get_auth_header(token):
    return {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}


def get_recently_played(token, start_date):
    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played"
    headers = get_auth_header(token)
    limit = 50 
    query = f"?limit={limit}"

    # Spotify requires the timestamp in milliseconds
    timestamp_ms = int(start_date.timestamp()) * 1000
    query += f"&after={timestamp_ms}"

    query_url = url + query
    result = get(query_url, headers=headers)
    print(result)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)#["items"]
    return json_result



access_token = get_token()
start_date = datetime(2023, 9, 10)
recently_played = get_recently_played(access_token, start_date)

for idx, item in enumerate(recently_played):
    song_name = item["track"]["name"]
    artist_name = item["track"]["artists"][0]["name"]
    print(f"{idx + 1}. {song_name} by {artist_name}")
```

## Authorization Code

Following the comment, I have now changed the `get_token()` function to:

```
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8888/callback"

def get_token_new():
    auth_url  = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
    token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"

    # Generate the authorization URL
    auth_params = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "response_type": "code",
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
        "scope": "user-read-recently-played",  # Add the required scope
    }

    authorization_url = auth_url + "?" + "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in auth_params.items()])
    print("Please visit the following URL to authorize your application:")
    print(authorization_url)

    # After user authorization, you will receive an authorization code
    authorization_code = input("Enter the authorization code from the URL: ")

    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    token_params = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": authorization_code,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    }

    auth_string = client_id + ":" + client_secret
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    token_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
    }

    result = post(token_url, headers=token_headers, data=token_params)

    # Transform to dictionary
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token
```

This somewhat works, but I always need to grab the code in the url which is a pain in the stomach. Is there any way to cache it?

Comment: "Since the Client Credentials flow does not include authorization, only endpoints that do not access user information can be accessed." - [Spotify Web API Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow)

Comment: @Ximzend Thank you. Does that mean it's not possible? If that's the case, why is there documentation about it? - [Recently Played](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-recently-played)

Oh wait. Maybe I need to use Authorization code. I found it [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization)

Comment: @Ximzend I tried to change `"grant_type"` from `"client_credentials"` to `"authorization_code"`. This doesn't quite work, it seems like I need a code of some sort

Comment: Good to see you got the Authorization code flow working. To handle the automatic code usage, you can read the solution under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292843/7111585

Comment: @Ximzend thanks! I have actually managed to implement it in the end, using a caching file!